# Using Symfony2 service definitions in Symfony4, with multiple services for the same class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-dependency-injection

I have the following service definition in Symfony2

```
app.service_1:
   class: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
   arguments:
       - '@snc_redis.default_cache'

app.service_2:
    class: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
    arguments:
        - '@snc_redis.scheduler_cache'
```

Now I'm planning to upgrade to Symnfony4 where I need to give classpath as the service name

```yaml
Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
   arguments:
       - '@snc_redis.default_cache'

Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
    arguments:
        - '@snc_redis.scheduler_cache'
```

Here the problem is it has the same name because we use the same classpath? How I can fix it? Can I use an alias with different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the definition.

When you need to create several services from the same class, using the FQCN as an identifier won't work. Using the fully qualified class name is recommended and a good practice, but it's not mandatory. It's practical most of the time, since you can omit the `class` argument, and you do not need to pick a name for each service.

Your original definition is perfectly compatible with Symfony 4 (or 5):

```yaml
app.service_1:
   class: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
   arguments:
       - '@snc_redis.default_cache'

app.service_2:
    class: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
    arguments:
        - '@snc_redis.scheduler_cache'
```

I would simply advise to use more descriptive identifiers than `service_1` and `service_2`.

Answer (score -1):

An other way is to use alias like explain in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html)

```yaml
services:
  Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore:
    public: false
    arguments:
      - '@snc_redis.default_cache'

  app.service_1:
    alias: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
    public: true

  Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore:
    arguments:
      - '@snc_redis.scheduler_cache'
  app.service_2:
    alias: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore
    public: true
```

You can also use `bind` and `autowire: true` for your arguments. But your variables in services.yml must be same as them declared in constructor of yours services.
Look something like this:

```yaml
services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      
    autoconfigure: true
    bind:
      $defaultCache: '@snc_redis.default_cache'
      $schedulerCache: '@snc_redis.scheduler_cache'

    Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\RedisStore:
      public: false
```

(or use bind only in your service declaration).

PS: caution in your example, you miss `:` after class path :)